# ASP.NET HTTP Handler not working on Godaddy.com

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my asp.net web application i used HTTP Handlers and it's working very fine in debug mode and also when i host the application on VPS server but when i hosted the application on Go daddy site then its not working and giving Internal Server error.
My handler name is "Manage Uploaded Files" and it's in "StPaulsAdmin.Admin namespace.
Configuration for HTTP handlers in my Web.Config is as below -

```
 <system.webServer>
     <!--START HTTP HANDLERS CONFIGURATION(REQUIRED TO HOST ON GO DADDY SITE)-->
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" >
      <add name="ManageUploadedFiles" type="StPaulsAdmin.Admin.UploadPageFiles,StPaulsAdmin.Admin" />
    </modules>
    <!--END-->
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: I've had so, so, so many problems with GoDaddy and ASP.net. I gave up on them for hosting. Even with a simple ASP site that worked perfectly locally and on a free Azure site, GoDaddy would throw errors (like, of the 500 sort) whenever I published it to them. So I can't say I'm overly surprised by this. For a while, and it still might be the case, they were listing IIS7 as the latest-and-greatest of that world, while the rest of us are on IIS8. I think they invest more in their website builder products than anything other people write.

Answer (score 0):

yes you are correct i have been face same problem, and not renew GoDaddy.They have some problem with asp.net deployment.

Comment: So what's solution of this problem.

Comment: Before purchasing a VPS or shared hosting,We should analyse what software and hardware and other utilities are required to run our application.then same ask for the provider if they have so purchase.Because many low cost hosting doesn't support full fledged dynamic application.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved by giving permissions to the httpdocs folder in which the site is hosted.